# Why got lack of memory error when importing with

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 10 app with [igaster/laravel_cities](https://github.com/igaster/laravel_cities) 1.3.12 I try import data in console and got lack of memory error:

```
php  -d memory_limit=6500M  artisan geo:seed UA --append  --chunk=10
Start seeding for UA
Reading File '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/storage/geo/UA.txt'
   0/100 [>---------------------------]   0%Opening File '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/storage/geo/hierarchy.txt'
 100/100 [============================] 100% Hierarcy building completed. 0 items loaded

Finished: 0 Countries imported.  10 orphan items skiped
Writing in Database
 100/100 [============================] 100%
Processed Batch 0
   1/100 [>---------------------------]   1%Opening File '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/storage/geo/hierarchy.txt'
 100/100 [============================] 100% Hierarcy building completed. 0 items loaded

Finished: 0 Countries imported.  10 orphan items skiped
Writing in Database
 100/100 [============================] 100%
Processed Batch 1
   2/100 [>---------------------------]   2%Opening File '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/storage/geo/hierarchy.txt'
 100/100 [============================] 100% Hierarcy building completed. 1 items loaded

Finished: 0 Countries imported.  9 orphan items skiped
Writing in Database
 100/100 [============================] 100%
Processed Batch 2
   3/100 [>---------------------------]   3%Opening File '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/storage/geo/hierarchy.txt'
 100/100 [============================] 100% Hierarcy building completed. 0 items loaded

Finished: 0 Countries imported.  10 orphan items skiped
Writing in Database
 100/100 [============================] 100%
Processed Batch 3
   5/100 [=>--------------------------]   5%Opening File '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/storage/geo/hierarchy.txt'
  46/100 [============>---------------]  46%PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 6815744000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/IncomingEntry.php on line 79
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/artisan:0
PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle($input = class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput { protected $definition = class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition { private array $arguments = [...]; private int $requiredCount = 1; private ?Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument $lastArrayArgument = NULL; private ?Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument $lastOptionalArgument = class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument { ... }; private array $options = [...]; private array $negations = [...]; private array $shortcuts = [...] }; protected $stream = NULL; protected $options = ['append' => TRUE, 'chunk' => '10']; protected $arguments = ['command' => 'geo:seed', 'country' => 'UA']; protected $interactive = TRUE; private array $tokens = [0 => 'geo:seed', 1 => 'UA', 2 => '--append', 3 => '--chunk=10']; private array $parsed = [] }, $output = class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput { private int ${Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output}verbosity = 32; private Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterInterface ${Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output}formatter = class Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter { private bool $decorated = TRUE; private array $styles = [...]; private Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyleStack $styleStack = class Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyleStack { ... } }; private ${Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput}stream = resource(2) of type (stream); private Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $stderr = class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput { private int ${Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output}verbosity = 32; private Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterInterface ${Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output}formatter = class Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter { ... }; private $stream = resource(3) of type (stream) }; private array $consoleSectionOutputs = [] }) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/artisan:35
...
PHP  27. Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch($event = class Illuminate\Log\Events\MessageLogged { public $level = 'warning'; public $message = 'Implicit conversion from float 46.58585890557657 to int loses precision in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/ProgressBar.php on line 362'; public $context = [] }, $payload = *uninitialized*, $halt = *uninitialized*) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php:248
PHP  28. Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->invokeListeners($event = 'Illuminate\\Log\\Events\\MessageLogged', $payload = [0 => class Illuminate\Log\Events\MessageLogged { public $level = 'warning'; public $message = 'Implicit conversion from float 46.58585890557657 to int loses precision in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/ProgressBar.php on line 362'; public $context = [...] }], $halt = FALSE) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:266
PHP  29. Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:453-459}($event = 'Illuminate\\Log\\Events\\MessageLogged', $payload = [0 => class Illuminate\Log\Events\MessageLogged { public $level = 'warning'; public $message = 'Implicit conversion from float 46.58585890557657 to int loses precision in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/ProgressBar.php on line 362'; public $context = [...] }]) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:286
PHP  30. Laravel\Telescope\Watchers\LogWatcher->recordLog($event = class Illuminate\Log\Events\MessageLogged { public $level = 'warning'; public $message = 'Implicit conversion from float 46.58585890557657 to int loses precision in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/ProgressBar.php on line 362'; public $context = [] }) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:458
PHP  31. Laravel\Telescope\IncomingEntry::make(...$arguments = variadic(['level' => 'warning', 'message' => 'Implicit conversion from float 46.58585890557657 to int loses precision in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/ProgressBar.php on line 362', 'context' => []])) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Watchers/LogWatcher.php:52
PHP  32. Laravel\Telescope\IncomingEntry->__construct($content = ['level' => 'warning', 'message' => 'Implicit conversion from float 46.58585890557657 to int loses precision in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/ProgressBar.php on line 362', 'context' => []], $uuid = *uninitialized*) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/IncomingEntry.php:92
PHP  33. array_merge(...$arrays = variadic(['hostname' => 'master-at-home'])) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/IncomingEntry.php:79

   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError

  Allowed memory size of 6815744000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

  at vendor/laravel/telescope/src/IncomingEntry.php:79
     75▕         $this->uuid = $uuid ?: (string) Str::orderedUuid();
     76▕
     77▕         $this->recordedAt = now();
     78▕
  ➜  79▕         $this->content = array_merge($content, ['hostname' => gethostname()]);
     80▕
     81▕         // $this->tags = ['hostname:'.gethostname()];
     82▕     }
     83▕

      +31 vendor frames
  32  artisan:35
      App\Console\Kernel::handle("class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput { protected $definition = class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition { private array $arguments = [...]; private int $requiredCount = 1; private ?Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument $lastArrayArgument = NULL; private ?Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument $lastOptionalArgument = class Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument { ... }; private array $options = [...]; private array $negations = [...]; private array $shortcuts = [...] }; protected $stream = NULL; protected $options = ['append' => TRUE, 'chunk' => '10']; protected $arguments = ['command' => 'geo:seed', 'country' => 'UA']; protected $interactive = TRUE; private array $tokens = [0 => 'geo:seed', 1 => 'UA', 2 => '--append', 3 => '--chunk=10']; private array $parsed = [] }", "class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput { private int ${Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output}verbosity = 32; private Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterInterface ${Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output}formatter = class Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter { private bool $decorated = TRUE; private array $styles = [...]; private Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyleStack $styleStack = class Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyleStack { ... } }; private ${Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput}stream = resource(2) of type (stream); private Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $stderr = class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput { private int ${Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output}verbosity = 32; private Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterInterface ${Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output}formatter = class Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter...")

  33  artisan:0
      {main}()

   Whoops\Exception\ErrorException

  Allowed memory size of 6815744000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

  at vendor/laravel/telescope/src/IncomingEntry.php:79
     75▕         $this->uuid = $uuid ?: (string) Str::orderedUuid();
     76▕
     77▕         $this->recordedAt = now();
     78▕
  ➜  79▕         $this->content = array_merge($content, ['hostname' => gethostname()]);
     80▕
     81▕         // $this->tags = ['hostname:'.gethostname()];
     82▕     }
     83▕

      +1 vendor frames
  2   [internal]:0
      Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()
```

I have in my OS, after I set 7056M in /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini with parameter  memory_limit = 7056M :

```
# free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         8040668     1679136     4623984      208516     1737548     5900784
Swap:        2104476           0     2104476
# php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
7056M
# php -v
PHP 8.2.11 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2023 09:47:18) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.11, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2023, by Derick Rethans
# uname -a
Linux master-at-home 6.2.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct  6 10:23:26 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

File UA.txt has 6.8 MiB - it not very big, why I got this error and how to fix it ?

Comment: It takes more memory than the file size to process it. Without code, it's hard to tell to optimize, but it needs at least a little bit more memory. The memory limit might be 7065M on the command line, but your command is explicitly setting the memory limit to `memory_limit=6500M`

Comment: My initial thought (without deeply looking at the code on github): either the progress bar or those chunks of 100 cities at a time don't get 'unset', so they're still taking up memory. After the progress bar has run and that chunk of 100 cities has been imported, try to unset those 2 variables

Comment: @aynbe, a) maybe just misspeling in your post : I do not have "7065M", but "7056M" b) Which value have I to set in my console command ?

Comment: Are you using [laravel/telescope](https://github.com/laravel/telescope)? It looks like a debug assistant, so it's probably storing everything in RAM to display it later. You probably need to disable or configure it.

Comment: @Álvaro González, You are right . I disabled telescope and it works ok. if you answer my question I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at where the error is being thrown, you'll see it's a library:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 6815744000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/**vendor/laravel/telescope**/src/IncomingEntry.php on line 79

If you locate the [package in packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/telescope), you can read it is "An elegant debug assistant for the Laravel framework". Debugging tools often collect variables in order to display them, and that's something you don't want when you deal with very large data sets. Either disable the assistant altogether or check whether it provides a setting to avoid this.

According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/telescope), you can disable data collection. That looks worth trying:

```
'enabled' => env('TELESCOPE_ENABLED', true),
```